# Azure APIM Gateway shows "401 Unauthorized" repeatedly despite the right product subscription keys for subscribers. HTTP Trial request fails

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

I have tried to execute a sample API created with API Management Service of Azure Instance.

It failed to receive an API success from Developer portal when launched from browser.

I triple checked the product subscription keys for all subscribers but it fails to process the API request by throwing "401 Unauthorized"

I have included the image of the error I am getting below.

[image]

Comment: Based on the response headers and the response-message, I guess the API is calling another API which fails due to authentication issues.

Comment: Did you refer to which document or what API you created to provide specific test information? Be careful to hide confidential information. This will help you better.